# Switch on an extensible class

Tags: java, class, enums, switch-statement

In Java, you can switch on an enum. Say you have something like

```
enum Color { RED, ORANGE, YELLOW ... }
```

you can then

```
switch (color) {
case RED:
    ...
```

Now, I have a particular requirement for switching on a class of objects, call them colors for the sake of illustration, *but also create more of them at runtime*. And you cannot do that with enums.

Of course, the switch statement can only know about the ones that are defined at compile time. That's okay. If at runtime I create teal, maroon and aquamarine, I still only need to switch on the basic colors like red, green and blue. But I need to be able to create the other ones.

Subclasses would do fine, if I could create `class OtherColor extends Color ...` but enums cannot subclass or be subclassed.

I could forget about enums and just create a regular class with some static instances... but then switch will not work on those.

The closest solution I know of is `class Color` together with `switch (color.toString())`. This is suboptimal because it means typos are not caught at compile time, and extra clock cycles must be spent doing string comparisons at runtime. (Second-best solution would be to assign integer ID tags, which harms maintainability of the code.)

Is there another solution?

Comment: Use a command pattern with the link between the color and the command in a map. Then use that map to select the command and execute it (optionally execute a 'default' command in case there is no mapping).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yeah, that's probably the best fallback if there is no good way to use a switch statement. Doesn't get the same syntactic convenience, but does get compile time typo checking, and runtime it's just a hash table lookup, so it should be pretty fast.

Comment: I’d consider it more than a fallback, it’s the clean solution.

Comment: I can't think of a good way to use a switch in this situation that wouldn't result in hard to understand or brittle code (ie the `toString()` or integer ID options).

Comment: What might work is having the API return an enum, and the standard implementation values return a specific enum value, and the runtime created classes a fallback value, and switch on that. But that is a convention that can be broken by a custom value returning the same enum value as a standard implementation, and it would also remove the flexibility of being able to add specific execution for non-standard types at runtime.

Comment: What will you do inside the switch cases? Could you just do this with polymorphism instead?